# Is Every (Real) Analytic Function (with Non-Degenerate MacLaurin Series) Asymptotically Greater Than any Polynomial?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

**Question:** Given a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the MacLaurin series exists and equals the function for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and such that for all $n \ge n_0$, $n_0$ some positive integer, the $n$th term of the series does not vanish, is it necessarily true that $x^{\epsilon}=o(f)$ for *every* $\epsilon > 0$?

(Note everywhere that I am taking the limit as $x \to \infty$, even though big and little Oh notation applies also to more general limits.)

---

**Motivation:** I just realized this simple proof for why the exponential function must grow asymptotically faster than *any* polynomial $P$.

Assume that $P$ is of degree $n$. Then take the $(n+1)$st term of the exponential's MacLaurin series (denote it $g$); then $P=o(g)$ and $g=O(e^x)$; hence it follows that $P=o(e^x)$.

If $\epsilon$ is non-integer, then just take the ceiling of $\epsilon$ and apply the argument above.

---

The above question is essentially -- how far can we extend the concepts in this proof? For instance, does the same reasoning allow us to show that $P=o(\Gamma)$ for any $P$? Can we also use a Taylor series proof to show that $e^x=o(\Gamma)$?

I like this proof because it has some nice corollaries.

---

**Natural Logarithm:** Since the Taylor expansion of the natural logarithm has no non-vanishing terms, and yet $ln(x) = o(x^\epsilon)$ for *every* $\epsilon > 0$, it must follow that the radius of convergence for its Taylor series is finite.

Assume this were not true; then a completely analogous proof as for the exponential above would hold, and the logarithm would be super-polynomial. This is a contradiction, since the logarithm is sub-polynomial.

---

**Sine and Cosine:** Both of these have MacLaurin series with infinite radii of convergence. Therefore it must follow that for both functions, infinitely many of the terms of their MacLaurin series vanish, or else again we would have a contradiction, since $\sin x=O(1)$ and $\cos x = O(1)$.

---

This is especially interesting to me because they are based on concepts most commonly applied in computer science and numerics (i.e. discrete mathematics), and yet these are very elegant and appealing proofs for basic calculus (the quintessential discipline of continuous mathematics).

Comment: The reason why it works for exponential function and not in general (see Hans' answer): power series expansion of $e^x$ has all coefficients of the same sign, so there is no cancellation, while in general we can have massive cancellation (like in case of $\sin(x)$ or $e^{-x}$).

Comment: @Wojowu Oh jeez you're right. Do you think I should submit another version of this question with "non-vanishing terms" replaced with "terms of the same sign"?

Comment: I am curious still about how the Taylor expansions of functions relate to their order of growth, specifically why Gamma must be superexponential (besides just "it interpolates the factorials"), why logarithm must be subpolynomial, and why sine and cosine are bounded. I think exponential is the only one for which the terms of the Taylor series are all of the same sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire function $f(x)=\sin x + \cos x$ is a counterexample to your statement. All Maclaurin coefficients are nonzero, yet $f$ is bounded on $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Oh wow you're right. This was an obvious counterexample to overlook. Do you think I should submit another version of this question with "non-vanishing terms" replaced with "terms of the same sign"? I am curious still about how the Taylor expansions of functions relate to their order of growth, specifically why Gamma must be superexponential (besides just "it interpolates the factorials"), why logarithm must be subpolynomial, and why sine and cosine are bounded. I think exponential is the only one for which the terms of the Taylor series are all of the same sign.

Comment: @William No need to ask another question - if you have a power series $f(x)$ with nonnegative coefficients and one of the terms is $cx^n,c>0$, then $f(x)\geq cx^n$ for $x>0$, so if you have infinitely many terms, all polynomials will be outgrown. Also, $e^x$ is definitely not the only function with nonnegative terms. $\sum\frac{x^n}{n!^2}$ is another such, and it's definitely not an exponential function.

Comment: I agree. What about how to show using power series that the gamma function grows faster than the exponential though? Or that the logarithm's power series can only have finite radius of convergence? Or that sine and cosine are bounded? I thought it had to do with vanishing/non-vanishing terms, but since it doesn't, I don't know how to prove any of them using changes of sign.

Comment: @Wojowu also for your example of $\Sigma \frac{x^n}{n!^2}$, how do we show whether or not the function is $o(e^x)$ or $\Theta(e^x)$? (It seems to clearly be $O(e^x)$, although I may be mistaken.)

Comment: @William, those are three different problems with three very different solutions, none of which can really be reduced to only checking the signs of the power series coefficients.

Comment: @William The Taylor expansion of $\Gamma(x)$ around $a$ doesn't have infinite radius of convergence no matter what $a$ you choose, and the same is true for logarithm so I don't think power series can tell us directly anything about the asymptotics. As for $\sin,\cos$, these are really subtle. If you were to change any (single) coefficient by any amount, then you would get a function which isn't bounded anymore. So the fact that $\sin$ is bounded doesn't only follow from the size of coefficients, but some deeper structure behind them. Again, I don't know of general methods to get such results.

Comment: @William Rather than asking new questions in the comments, you should [post a new Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask),